# Which groups does $U(2)$ cover?

Tags: lie-groups, covering-spaces

I can guarantee that $SU(2)$ covers only itself and $SO(3)$ because its center is the group $\{\pm I\}$. Then, as the kernel of a covering map of Lie groups is a discrete central subgroup, it must be a subgroup of $\{\pm I\}$.

But the center of $U(2)$ is $S^1\cdot I$. Thus, the discrete central subgroups of $U(2)$ are the cyclic groups defined by the roots of unity. But given such a cyclic group can one guarantee that there is a covering map from $U(2)$ whoose kernel is this cyclic group?

As the center of $U(2)$ is a circle, the base of this covering must have a central circle as well.

Comment: Yes, always, just take the quotient by the cyclic group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I see! Then it will just quotient the central circle. Therefore $U(2)$ cannot cover any other group but itself. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you thinking that the quotients of $U(2)$ by the discrete central subgroups are all isomorphic to $U(2)$? That is not true. For example the quotient by $\{ \pm 1 \}$ contains $SO(3)$ (the image of $SU(2)$) as a subgroup, but $U(2)$ doesn't have this property because $SO(3)$ has no nontrivial $2$-dimensional complex irreducible representations.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Isn't $U(2)=U(1)\cdot SU(2)$? That is, an element of $U(2)$ is of the form $zA$, with z in the central circle and $A\in SU(2)$. The quotient here wouldn't just act on this circle?

Comment: I don't know what that last sentence means. It is true that $U(2) = U(1) \cdot SU(2)$ but that doesn't imply the result you want about quotients.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is this correct to say that this quotient is $U(1)\cdot SO(3)$ if the order of the cyclic group is even and $U(2)$ if it is odd?

Comment: To be clear, $\cdot$ does not imply $\times$; that is, $U(2)$ is not isomorphic to the direct product of the groups $U(1) \times SU(2)$ (e.g. they have different centers).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I know. But there aren't many compact conneceted Lie group that are non-abelian, that have a central circle, a copy of SU(2) or of SO(3) and have dimension $4$. So, I'm trying to understand who exactly are they.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking in terms of $U(2)$ alone is confusing me a little so I am going to pull back to a double cover. $U(2)$ admits $U(1) \times SU(2)$ as its unique double cover, with covering map

$$U(1) \times SU(2) \ni (z, X) \mapsto zX \in U(2).$$

as you mentioned in the comments, where we implicitly use the embedding of $U(1)$ into $U(2)$ as the scalar multiples of the identity. The kernel of this map is the diagonal copy of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ generated by $(-1, -1)$. Now we can understand the quotient of $U(2)$ by the discrete central copy of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ by pulling it back to this double cover; if $n$ is odd the corresponding subgroup of $U(1) \times SU(2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/(2n)$, embedded as

$$\mathbb{Z}/(2n) \ni k \mapsto (\exp \left( \frac{2 \pi i k}{n} \right), (-1)^k) \in U(1) \times SU(2)$$

and if $n$ is even the corresponding subgroup is $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, embedded as

$$\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \ni (k, \pm 1) \mapsto (\exp \left( \frac{2 \pi i k}{n} \right), \pm 1) \in U(1) \times SU(2).$$

It follows that when $n$ is even the quotient is isomorphic to $U(1) \times SO(3)$ as you said in the comments. When $n$ is odd we can perform the quotient by first quotienting by the element $2 \in \mathbb{Z}/(2n)$, which allows us to ignore the $(-1)^k$ bit and gives another copy of $U(1) \times SU(2)$, then quotient by $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/(2n)$, which now acts by $(-1, -1)$, so we get a group isomorphic to $U(2)$.

I have to admit that this is a surprise to me! I was misled by an analogy to the group $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ which turned out to be invalid. I really am actually surprised that $U(2)$ covers itself nontrivially.